# Can a wizard delay learning new spells from leveling up, and instead learn different spells later?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, character-advancement

Can a wizard delay learning new spells from leveling up, and instead learn different spells later?

For example, can a 2nd-level wizard choose to skip adding two new spells to their spellbook from leveling up, and instead add four 2nd-level spells when they reach 3rd level?

Comment: Hi Ara, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] when you have a chance. Since this has drawn a "unclear what you are asking" vote, I've edited your question to try to clarify what I think you were asking. Please let me know (by including @NathanS in your comment) if I've misinterpreted, as any edits can be rolled back.

Comment: Hi Ara, it is worth saying that as a DM I would allow this, because the new spells represent you learning, and everyone can learn at their own pace. If you want to convince your DM to allow you to do this (Assuming the answer ends up as no) it might be worth asking a question on the balance implications of allowing such a rule.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Spells are learned upon level up

From the [wizard class features](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ClassFeatures):

> **Learning Spells of 1st Level and Higher**
>
> Each time you gain a wizard level, you can add two wizard spells of your choice to your spellbook for free.

So if you want these free spells, they must be chosen when leveling up. You can't wait for the next level up to add four spells instead. You *can* choose not to add spells when leveling up (the wording does say "you can add") but this does not grant you any benefit.